# XAML - Using fonts from resource dictionary from another assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml, fonts, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I am building an application that uses `ResourceDictionaries` from another assembilies and I'm having problems with using fonts.

There is an assembly named **MyFontAssembly** that stores fonts along with references to them as an `ResourceDictionary`. The structure of it looks as follows:

```
MyFontAssembly
    - FontDictionary.xaml - (stores references to fonts)
    - Fonts
        - FontA.ttf
        - FontB.ttf
          ...
```

There is also another assembly that stores `ResourceDictionaries` for styling controls and it's called **MyStylesAssembly**. ResourceDictionaries from MyStylesAssembly are then merged in an App.xaml of an application in order to provide reusable styles.

**The problem is that my styles does recognise font resources** (the code is not crashing because it couldn't find resource by its key), **but it looks like fonts stored as ttf files were not applied.**

I have tried the following in my `FontDictionary.xaml`, but none of it works:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="MyFontKey">Fonts/#MyFontName</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="MyFontKey">pack://application:,,,/MyFontAssemblyName;Component/Fonts/#MyFontName</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="MyFontKey">/MyFontAssemblyName;Component/Fonts/#MyFontName</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="MyFontKey">pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#MyFontName</FontFamily>
```

**NOTE:**

- I am sure that my fonts form ttf work and are named correctly. I was using `<FontFamily x:Key="MyFontKey">Fonts/#MyFontName</FontFamily>` implementation in the single exe project with the same structure and everything was just fine, the problem appeared when I have split the implementation into few assemblies, just like I described, during refactoring.
- `MyFontAssembly` is merged in `MyStylesAssembly` correctly. I just call it by that name here, in real code it has also a few more `ResourceDictionaries` that are used correctly by `MyStylesAssembly`. The problem appears to be with just `<FontFamily>` tags not recognising ttf files.
- `MyFontAssembly` and `MyStylesAssembly` are projects of tyle `ClassLibrary` and does not contain any code other than in `ResourceDictionaries` (no classes or code behind)

Comment: Are you using the correct refrence. U need to refer XAML URI package document conventions if not working

Comment: I most likely don't use the correct way to reference fonts, but I don't know what is the correct way to do it (that's kinda my question, here).

Comment: Update Sample with example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640679/wpf-custom-fontfamily-from-assembly). I had to set `build action` to `resource`, then reference them by using:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="MyFontKey">pack://application:,,,/MyFontAssemblyName;Component/Fonts/#MyFontName</FontFamily>
```

or the shorter version:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="MyFontKey">/MyFontAssemblyName;Component/Fonts/#MyFontName</FontFamily>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Create A WPF Class Library.Lets Say FontLibraryCommon**
[image]

**Now Delete App.Xaml and MainWIndow.Xaml as shown below**
[image]

**Now change the project properties to class library and compile**

[image]

**Now Add Font Folder and existing TTF files under it as shown. I use Pacifico font for example**
[image]
[image]

**Now add ResourceDictioanry let say FontDictioanry.xaml in your library
and your xaml should look like this**

> Here is the code

```
  <ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FontLibraryCommon">
   <FontFamily x:Key="Pacifico">Fonts/#Pacifico</FontFamily>

 </ResourceDictionary>
```

**Now in your other project add Font Library as reference 
And in your MainWindow.Xaml `**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/FontLibraryCommon;component/FontDictioanry.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>`
```

**And last Lets Say label you can set like this**

```
<Label FontFamily="{StaticResource Pacifico}"> Raman</Label>
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I have done in my application. (Also there is a ClassLibrary project type when you create a new project, so you don't have to delete App.xaml and change output type)

Comment: so what issue you are facing? It will work only on run time

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to reference a font from deferent library.
Say we have library called `MyAwesomeFonts` and here is its project structure:

```
MyAwesomeFontsLibrary
 |
 |__ Fonts\
 |      |
 |      |__ Fonts.cs
 |      |__ MyAwesomeFont.ttf
 |
 |__ Themes\
        |
        |__ generic.xaml
```

In the `Fonts\` folder you put your fonts, and in the generic.xaml file you declare your font normally like this:

```
xmlns:fonts="clr-namespace:MyAwesomeFontsLibrary.Fonts"...
<FontFamily 
     x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type fonts:Fonts}, ResourceId=MyAwesomeFont}">Fonts/#My Awesome Font Name</FontFamily>
```

and in the `Fonts.cs` file contains:

```
// say this class declared in namespace: MyAwesomeLibrary.Fonts
public class Fonts
{
    public static ComponentResourceKey MyAwesomeFontKey => new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(Fonts), "MyAwesomeFont");
}
```

**For every font you have you do the same things done above, you add them to `Fonts` folder, declare them as resource in `generic.xaml` file and finally create a static property in `Fonts.cs`**

Now build your library, add reference to it in project where you want to use it and add a namespace of your AwesomeFontsLibrary to your XAML something like that:

```
<... xmlns:fonts="clr-namespace:MyAwesomeFontsLibrary.Fonts;assembly=MyAwesomeFontsLibrary" >
```

Now here is two snippets of reusing your AwesomeFontsLibrary Fonts in `TextBlock` and `style`:

In Style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBlockStyle"
           TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static fonts:Fonts.MyAwesomeFontKey}}"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

Or directly in Textblock:

```
    <TextBlock FontFamily="{DynamicResource {x:Static fonts:Fonts.MyAwesomeFontKey}}" FontSize="50">Welcome!</TextBlock>
```

> **You must use Dynamic Resource, not static resource, when using a ComponentResourceKey**
>
> **Your new font my not appear in designer window but in runtime it will work.**

**Steps above are tested on my machine and they work. Hopefully this will help.**

Comment: Using DynamicResource instead of StaticResource could work. I didn't think about it. Anyways I have found a solution to my problem on the another question on the stack. I had to set my font files build action to resource and it works.